# Is there a way to get primary key values from dynamodb without knowing the value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to query my DynamoDB table based on multiple primary keys in the table. I want it to then return the value based on the primary key. I am using boto3 python sdk to write a script to retrieve this information.

However, the problem I am coming across is it seems that all the calls to DynamoDb I am looking at requires that you know the value of the partition key as well.

For example, batch get item says I can do this using an attribute; however, it the example it has a key and a value passed in the request. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple primary keys"? There can be only one primary key in a given table.

Comment: If your table has a composite key (partition key *and* sort key) then a query on the partition key alone will return all items with a matching partition key i.e. it will return multiple items if there are multiple matching items (with different sort keys).

Comment: If you don't know any part of your item's key then the scan operation will return all items.

Comment: Scan operation worked @jarmod

Comment: Just be aware that scan always reads the entire table (assuming you use the pagination fully) so will be potentially inefficient for tables with many items.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know any part of your item's key then the scan operation will return all items.

If your table has a composite key (partition key and sort key) and you know at least the partition key value of interest, then a query on the partition key alone will return all items with a matching partition key i.e. it will return multiple items if there are multiple matching items (with different sort keys).